# jquery sortable and dragable not running

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

i am using code on following link for drag-able and sortable

```
<http://skfox.com/jqExamples/SortableSelectable.html>
```

[Code](http://skfox.com/jqExamples/SortableSelectable.html)

now i have two implement this thing in a page two times
 but when it implement on page twice . Elements id's are conflicting .
Then i change there id i stop working .

in short i want to implement this stuff on a page twice .

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: One ID per element is allowed. If you want it twice, you'll have to change IDs on the second and call sortable/draggable once more but for those IDs

Answer (score 1):

Look a at the example here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists

You should give each of your element an unique id, otherwise it won't work.
Maybe you could make a fiddle so we can see what's wrong in your code.